# как обрезать изображение в php?

Tags: php

есть php код, который генерирует картинку.

Картинка получается из 1-й полупрозрачной картинки (бело-синяя картинка) , которая накладывается на фон(церковь).

Всё бы и ничего, НО есть проблема!
картинка с церковью слишком большая, а все мои попытки добавить imagecrop и задать координаты ведут лишь к ошибкам.

Если проще, то сейчас картинка выглядет так (слева), а должно получиться так (справа) т.е. обрезаются лишние края, которые больше чем сине-белая полупрозрачная картинка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот сам код:

> 

```
$img            = imagecreatefrompng("res/bg.png");
$img_cover2         = imagecreatefrompng("res/im2.png");

$quality        = 90;
$temp           = "";
$img_cover = imagecreatetruecolor(1240, 750);       






/*-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Накладываем полупрозрачный фон
------------------------------------------------------------------*/
imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagealphablending($img_cover2, true);
imagesavealpha($img_cover, true);    
imagecopy($img, $img_cover2, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($img_cover), imagesy($img_cover));


    
header('Content-Type: image/png');



# Save Image
$im=imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);             

    $img = imagecreate(800, 600);
```

помогите пожалуйста, уже пятые сутки мучаюсь...(((( плакать хочется

Comment: лого текст и дата наверное в данном коде избыточны? оставьте тот код, которые демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: готово,, убрал)

Comment: не особо ясно, есть у вас картинка, есть слой который накладываете. но почему то появляется какой-то `img_cover` с заданными 1240х750, и его размеры вы используете при копировании и наложении в `imagecopy`, вместо верхних двух

Comment: его я поставил чтоб фиксировать размеры полупрозрачной бело-голубой картинки)

Comment: Создайте пустое изображение нужного размера. Потом скопируйте туда город (часть нужного размера). Потом скопируйте голубой фон.

Comment: или добавьте `imagecrop` для вашего результата. либо после загрузки города сразу обрежьте его по размеру голубого фона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в целом решение видится таким. Вы загружаете две картинки, фон и голубой оверлей

```
$bg = imagecreatefrompng(...);
$overlay =  ....;
```

далее сразу обрезаете фон по размеру оверлея.

```
$res = imagecrop($bg, [
             'x' => 0, 
             'y' => 0, 
             'width' => imagesx($overlay),
             'height' => imagesy($overlay)
          ]);
```

потом устаналиваете все ваши прозрачности и на полученное изображенеи накладываете фон

```
imagecopy($res, $overlay, 0,0, 0, 0, imagesx($ovelay), imagesy($overlay));
```

Comment: спасибо) это еще я протупил. не посмотрел на то какая у меня версия php)))